# Obter utilizador autenticado no construtor

Tags: laravel-5.3

Depois de muito pesquisar e dar uma olhadela na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors), percebo perfeitamente que e o porque não dá para fazer à "moda antiga", mas queria uma solução/workaround para fazer o seguinte:

Tenho uma classe base, não é chamada diretamente na requisição, não é esta que está declarada nas rotas:

```
class AdminPanelController extends Controller
{
    protected $_authUser;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
             $this->_authUser = Auth::guard('admin')->user();
             dd($this->_authUser); // tudo bem
             return $next($request);
        });
    }
    ...
    protected function yoo() {
        dd($this->_authUser); // null, mas precisava disto aqui
    }
}
```

Precisava que o utilizador autenticado estivesse disponivel, no metodo `yoo()`, sendo que o controller chamado diretamente com a requisição:

```
Route::get('users', 'UsersController@hey');
```

UsersController:

```
class UsersController extends AdminPanelController 
{

    protected params;

    public function __construct(Request $request) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->params = $this->yoo(); // auth user é null, mas precisava de chamar o metodo aqui
    }
    ...
}
```

Nota que se chamar o metodo `$this->yoo()` em outro sítio que não o construtor já funciona bem, mas preciso mesmo de o chamar no construtor.

NOTA: Eu também tentei `$request->user()` com o resultado `Authentication user provider [] is not defined.`, como isto é um sistema de multiautenticação teria de definir um guard: `$request->guard('admin')->user()` que deu: `Method guard does not exist`

Comment: Porque ele está sendo atribuido dentro do método `middleware`?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, sinceramente vi esta solução pelos docs que estão no link. Mas não me ajudou muito

Comment: @VirgilioNovic , o problema não é com o middleware que verifica se está ou não autenticado, esse funciona perfeitamente

Comment: sim sim entendi, não disse também que é um problema só questionei o porque de fazer isso dentro do `middleware` ai você explicou que está na documentação para `Laravel 5.3.4`.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, mas é como te digo, a mim parece-me que com isso ou sem isso é igual. Vou acresentar uma informação extra à questão

Comment: Realmente não funciona, eu parto da premissa que o `middleware` executa primeiro e nesse caso não, posso estar até enganado, mas, eu testei os códigos e não tem acesso no `construtor` somente nos métodos quando o mesmo já executou aquele `middleware`. Tanto é que se eu colocar no construtor da classe AdminPanelController na última linha `echo $this->_authUser;` não tem nada, porque ainda não foi executado. A documentação em alguns casos deixa a desejar, infelizmente.

Comment: Mas muito obgado @VirgilioNovic, por ter tentado ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Tenta algo assim:

```
class AdminPanelController extends Controller
{
    protected $_authUser;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware([$this, 'getAuthUserFromMiddleware']);
    }

    public function getAuthUserFromMiddleware($request, $next){
        $this->_authUser = Auth::guard('admin')->user();
        return $next($request);
    }

    protected function yoo() {
        return $this->_authUser;
    }
}

class UsersController extends AdminPanelController 
{
    protected params;

    public function __construct(Request $request) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->params = $this->yoo();
    }
}
```

Ou assim colocando o `use` na função:

```
class AdminPanelController extends Controller
{
    protected $_authUser;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) use($this->_authUser) {
             $this->_authUser = Auth::guard('admin')->user();
             return $next($request);
        });
    }

    protected function yoo() {
       return $this->_authUser;
    }
}
```

Comment: Não deu, e essa ultima dá erro de sintaxe, por causa da "->" dentro do `use`. Mas Obrgado por tentares