# Problemas com sessão laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Estou com problemas para setar e pegar itens de uma `sessão`, neste caso estou setando qual página devo marca no menu como `active`.

No `__contruct` de meu `controller` eu estou fazendo assim:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    session()->put('pagina', 'I');
}
```

E nas minhas páginas aonde esta o menu esta assim:

```
<li {{((Session('pagina') == 'H')? 'class="active"' : '')}}>
    <a href="/"><i class="zmdi zmdi-home"></i> Home</a>
</li>
<li {{((Session('pagina') == 'C')? 'class="active"' : '')}}>
    <a href="/igrejas"><i class="zmdi zmdi-assignment-account"></i> Igreja</a>
</li>
<li {{((Session('pagina') == 'I')? 'class="active"' : '')}}>
    <a href="/celulas"><i class="zmdi zmdi-accounts-alt"></i> {{ (($igreja->FLG_MODEL_IGREJ == 'C')? 'Celulas' : (($igreja->FLG_MODEL_IGREJ == 'P')? 'Pequenos Grupos' : 'Salas dominicais' )) }}</a>
</li>
```

Porém o menu não esta vindo marcado, dei um `dd` na `Session` e está voltando `null`, o que fazer ?

Tentei adicionar também em funções do meu controller e também não tive exito como no exemplo de baixo:

```
public function index(){
    session()->put('pagina', 'I');


    if(Auth::user()->FLG_USUAR_MASTE == 1) {
        return view('aa');
    }else{
        return view('aa');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso está [especificado](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors) e não vejo o porquê de nesta versão (5.3) terem feito isso assim, mas a verdade é que aceder à sessão/utilizador autenticado no construtor já não é suportado, há pouco tempo também [andei "desesperado"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/174086/obter-utilizador-autenticado-no-construtor) por uma solução mas não arranjei um workaround que resultasse, o meu conselho é que sigas a [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors) mas no meu caso não resultou (mais tarde reparei que era por a versão do meu projeto ser menor que a 5.3.4).

O conselho que te posso dar neste caso é que faças esta operação `session()->put('pagina', 'I');` no metodo chamado pela rota (ou outro) em vez de no construtor.

[Aqui](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-53-authuser-available-in-controller) e na documentação vejo que:

> Before using this feature, make sure that your application is running Laravel 5.3.4 or above:

Ou seja, deves estar a correr uma versão 5.3.4 ou maior, senão essa solução não resulta, e deves optar mesmo por usar a tua `session` noutro metodo que não o construtor. Para veres a versão em que o teu projeto está faz: `php artisan --version`